# Table view won't respond

Tags: ios4, uikit

I have a BarTableViewController that derives from UITableViewController.
It's my main view and so is loaded automatically when the app starts, and that instance of the class works fine.

Now I am trying to have that original instance push another instance of the same class like this:

```
BarTableViewController *bar = [[[BarViewController alloc] initForFoo:theFoo] autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:bar animated:YES];
```

The initForFoo method looks like this:

```
- (id)initForFoo:(Foo *)theFoo
{
    if ((self = [self initWithNibName:@"BarTableViewController" bundle:nil])) {
        self.foo = theFoo;
    }
    return self;
}
```

The push works and the view loads, and works fine in the simulator.

However on my iPhone 4 the table view is not responsive in this second instance: sliding my finger up and down the screen does nothing. If I tap in the search bar then tap cancel, the table then becomes responsive.

If I just call init instead if initWithNibName then the table view responds correctly even the first time, but of course none of my IBOutlet stuff gets bound.

This appears to be a one-time only thing: once I've done the search-and-cancel the table will respond, and even if I hit the back button then come back to this same instance of the view controller again, it won't get stuck.

What am I doing wrong here?

UPDATE:
I did have this guy as RootViewController in my MainWindow.xib. I tried taking that
out and making the app delegate create him, but still same behavior: everything
works except for the table view not scrolling. But now the initial instance also is frozen.

So, whenever I explicitly called initWithNibName I get this frozen behavior.

UPDATE2:
I've been commenting out different chunks of viewDidLoad and it seems to work all the time if I omit this:

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```

Of course that means I get no toolbar. I've tried putting it back in with no toolbar items, and it still exhibits the problem.

UPDATE3:
Breaking in with GDB while it's in this state, this is what I find in the UITableView:

```
(gdb) p * [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] searchViewController]
  <UITableViewController> = {
    <UIViewController> = {
      <UIResponder> = {
        <NSObject> = {
          isa = 0x9fe44
        }, <No data fields>}, 
      members of UIViewController: 
      _view = 0xa27600, 
      _tabBarItem = 0x0, 
      _navigationItem = 0x4d6dcc0, 
      _toolbarItems = 0x0, 
      _title = 0x0, 
      _nibName = 0xb9120, 
      _nibBundle = 0x242b40, 
      _parentViewController = 0x4d6de90, 
      _childViewControllers = 0x0, 
      _childModalViewController = 0x0, 
      _parentModalViewController = 0x0, 
      _modalTransitionView = 0x0, 
      _modalPreservedFirstResponder = 0x0, 
      _defaultFirstResponder = 0x0, 
      _dimmingView = 0x0, 
      _dropShadowView = 0x0, 
      _presentationSuperview = 0x0, 
      _sheetView = 0x0, 
      _currentAction = 0x0, 
      _savedHeaderSuperview = 0x0, 
      _savedFooterSuperview = 0x0, 
      _editButtonItem = 0x0, 
      _searchDisplayController = 0x4d7b290, 
      _popoverController = 0x0, 
      _modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical, 
      _modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen, 
      _lastKnownInterfaceOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait, 
      _contentSizeForViewInPopover = {
        width = 320, 
        height = 1100
      }, 
      _formSheetSize = {
        width = 0, 
        height = 0
      }, 
      _viewControllerFlags = {
        appearState = 2, 
        isEditing = 0, 
        isPerformingModalTransition = 0, 
        hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = 0, 
        autoresizesArchivedViewToFullSize = 0, 
        viewLoadedFromControllerNib = 0, 
        isRootViewController = 0, 
        isSheet = 0, 
        isSuspended = 0, 
        wasApplicationFrameAtSuspend = 0, 
        wantsFullScreenLayout = 0, 
        shouldUseFullScreenLayout = 0, 
        allowsAutorotation = 1, 
        searchControllerRetained = 1, 
        oldModalInPopover = 0, 
        isModalInPopover = 0, 
        restoreDeepestFirstResponder = 0, 
        isInWillRotateCallback = 0, 
        disallowMixedOrientationPresentations = 0, 
        modalPresentationsAreCurrentContext = 0
      }
    }, 
    members of UITableViewController: 
    _tableViewStyle = UITableViewStylePlain, 
    _keyboardSupport = 0x4d87540, 
    _tableViewControllerFlags = {
      clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = -1
    }
  },
```

I've tried a few blind isFirstResponder stabs in gdb with no luck.

Comment: I have a hunch it might be a "First Responder" issue. Some minor element is not giving up being first responder, so your scroll view is unresponsive...

Comment: How would I track that down? I'm not explicit setting a first responder in this one: it's just a UITableViewController with a nav bar etc-pretty standard. I'm sure I'm doing something stupid though. It could definitely be timing related, since it works in the simulator, and first responders and timing tend to be related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read:

> If you create your view controller and its view in the same NIB, and you nest the view underneath the view controller, it will adjust the view's frame automatically.

in [an answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247647/offset-on-uiwindow-addsubview) and this inspired me to try editing my XIB and adding a ViewController and putting the TableView under that—previously I had to ViewController in the XIB and TableView was at the top level.

This fixes my "frozen table view' issue, but I still don't really understand why: I did a bunch of before-and-after examining of frame sizes of the various components and couldn't tell what had changed. But it's fixed at least.