# [self.window addSubview:[_viewController view]]; moving the view up in lower version of iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, ios3.0

I am working on a universal application.I am using

`self.window.rootViewController = self.SecondViewController`

to load viewcontroller class in the `AppDelegate` method.
This line of code  is working fine for ios versions 4 and later but when i run it on my ios 3.1.3 it crashes.

So I replaced that code with `[self.window addSubview:[SecondViewController view]]` and it works fine but initially the view moves up(As in the screen shot) when we load the app for the first time.

So kindly help me overcome this issue
thank you [image]

Comment: Why... 1. dod you use the Xcode tag? (Now go read its tag wiki!) 2. would you want to support iOS 3?

Comment: first time check witch device version you r using as per device version set your code

Comment: @Ayaz: i am using ios 3.1.3.In which the view is moving up and it makes my app look weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `rootViewController` property was introduced with iOS 4.0, that is the reason for the crash in iOS 3.1.3.

If you use `[self.window addSubview:[SecondViewController view]]` then it can happen that the view controllers view is not adjusted for the status bar. See [Offset on UIWindow addSubview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247647/offset-on-uiwindow-addsubview) for a good explanation.

The solution is to assign the view's frame, in your case

```
self.SecondViewController.view.frame = [UIScreen mainScreen].applicationFrame;
```

before adding it as subview.

Answer (score 2):

```
SecondViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 460);
[self.window addSubview:[SecondViewController view]]
```