# ipad app wont fill the bottom of the screen

Tags: ios, ipad

I have a ipad app that allways displays with a white border at the bottom of the ipad screen like in this screenshot:

[image]

The problem is both in the retina/non retina simulator and ipads.

The app is just a uiView that is not set to any special sizes. Does anyone have a hint to what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the wantsFullScreenLayout property of your view controller to yes.

```
[myViewController setWantsFullScreenLayout:YES];
```

Comment: That did not work, but you still solved my problem, searching SO for this gave me this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247647/offset-on-uiwindow-addsubview/2248309#2248309 which solved my issue.